# Set URL prefix for ExtJS

Tags: extjs, extjs4, extjs-mvc, extjs4.2

I have an ExtJS 4 project using MVC architecture.

The server URL to the project is `http://myServer/myProject`, but ExtJS is ignoring the project name, giving me a 404 error (cannot find `http://myServer/app/view/Viewport.js`)

How do I tell ExtJS to prepend the project name before the URL paths?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use app folder property to let it know where to start looking for your files:

```
Ext.application({
   name:'MyExtApp',
   appFolder:'js/MyApp/app',
...
```